# Liferay /web/guest/home

Tags: liferay

Quick question.

For some reason links referencing the home page contain an extra `/web/guest/home` in them leading to

> "page not found error"

For example if I click on my company logo I get:

> Not Found The requested resource was not found.
>
> http://localhost:8080/web/guest/web/guest/home

As you can see there is an extra `"/web/guest"` in there.

How do I fix this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is is *all* links or *some*?

If you're talking about web content, where you set the links yourself, it might be that you've created links to "web/guest/home" instead of "/web/guest/home" - I guess this could lead to links relative to the current page.

Otherwise, if the problem still persists, please provide more details about what links link to /web/guest/web/guest/home.

As this has been open for quite some time: I guess the [liferay forums](http://www.liferay.com/web/guest/community/forums) would provide a quicker answer for this kind of question. If you've got the answer there, please post a link here.